# Can't fire blur event in IE10 MVC from partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-10, blur, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a problem with an MVC application, with IE10 and .blur() jquery event. It works fine with firefox or crhome.
I'm using jquery 1.8.3, but I've tested with 2 and appears the same problem.

Here is a fragment of js file:

```
 $(document).on('focus', "#gridTable input[type='text'].disabled", function () {
    $(this).blur();
});
```

Here the fragment of html file generated by a partial view:

```
<table id="gridTable">
<thead>
    ...
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        ...
        <td>
            <input class="numeric disabled" type="text" value="0" name="number-0">
        </td>
    ...
</tbody>
```

The idea is focus out the input when it contains 'disabled' class. It works on firefox and chrome without problems, but not in IE10.

Here is an online example: http://jsfiddle.net/rqFAH/7/
I've tested to change click event inestead of focus and it works, but it is slow and you can put any char if you are fast.

Thans a lot

Comment: Please just disable the input.

Comment: Thanks gdoron, but I can't disabled any input, they are placed in a form and I need all values and states (disabled, or not)